# How can I load modules based on condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, amd

I am using requirejs I have several condition to start my with many modules and plugins.
I would like to load the modules and required plugins after user passes the several condition.

Use case:

initially load screen for login
after authentication load another module 
that check several conditions
on success of all conditions 
I would like to load all the plugins and other modules.

How can I get it with requirejs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing that is simply using a condition and loading your script inside of it.

Example:

```
define('foo', function(require) {
    if (/* condition */) {
        require(['module'], function (module) {
            // the module stuff
        });
    }
});
```

You can see a live demo conditionally loading jquery at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3SW6/)

Also take a look at: [How to achieve lazy loading with RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911044/how-to-achieve-lazy-loading-with-requirejs)

Comment: This will not work, as requireJs hasn't load the module yet. The only way lazy loading is working is requiring the module with a callback function like in your linked SO.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle According to the documentation that should work (take a look at "Setting Exported Value" topic in the page I linked). I even tested it on my machine when I read your comment.

Comment: It will only work if the module is loaded yet. The question was about loading the module later on. So even your solution is working, it is working cause the module is still loaded in the initial payload.