# Every once in a while IE 9 fails to load javascript resources

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, requirejs

Every once in a while when i load my website about one in five times it fails to load the website and in the IE 9 console it says:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'normalize': object is null or undefined 
require.js, line 929 character 25
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'normalize': object is null or undefined 
require.js, line 929 character 25
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'extend': object is null or undefined 
Module.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 52 character 3
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'normalize': object is null or undefined 
require.js, line 929 character 25
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'View': object is null or undefined 
View.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 8 character 3
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set value of the property 'Validation': object is null or undefined 
backbone.validation.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 15 character 3
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'extend': object is null or undefined 
Class.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 10 character 3
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
hbs.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 143 character 15
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
hbs.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 143 character 15
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
hbs.js?ts=@@timestamp, line 143 character 15
SCRIPT5022: Load timeout for modules: css!lib/foundation/style_unnormalized2,css!lib/icon-font/fontcustom_unnormalized3,css!lib/icon-font/icon-font_unnormalized4,hbs!modules/header/HeaderTemplate_unnormalized5,css!modules/header/HeaderStyle_unnormalized6,hbs!lib/components/avatar/AvatarTemplate_unnormalized7,css!lib/components/avatar/AvatarStyle_unnormalized8,hbs!modules/login/LoginTemplate_unnormalized9,css!modules/login/LoginStyle_unnormalized10,hbs!modules/header/HeaderTemplate,hbs!lib/components/avatar/AvatarTemplate,hbs!modules/login/LoginTemplate
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
require.js, line 1758 character 9
```

what is so confusing is that it only happens sporadically could it be the way i'm requiring my javascript files?

Comment: It would be useful to see how you're loading your files. Show some code?

Comment: Possibly the module dependencies aren't setup correctly?

Comment: This sounds like your dependencies aren't set up correctly. 4 out of 5 times, your browser probably loads the scripts fast enough that it works and every now and then, it does not. As with everything: please post code when asking questions or it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be associated with a similar issue that happened in [JQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282#comment:1)

This is all about the DOM not being ready and since the DOM is NOT fully loaded this error occurs that would also explains the "random" behavior that you referred to.

If you have not done it yet try adding your scripts at the end of the page or some sort of lazy loading:

- http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/
- [How to achieve lazy loading with RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911044/how-to-achieve-lazy-loading-with-requirejs)

By the way only post on this regard seems Microsoft rejected it did not consider it a bug:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/792880/document-readystat