# Custom usage of RequireJS require() function

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm wondering why can't I use the `require()` function with something like this:

```
// I'm using define's sugar syntax
define(function(require) {  

  // This works fine. It assigns myModule to the myModule variable (no callback needed)
  var myModule = require('myModule');

  var getModule = function(name) {

    // This doesn work. Using require() here expects a callback
    return require(name);        
  };

  return getModule;
});
```

That second `require()` call throws (but taking a look with DevTools shows that `<name>` is actually loaded):

```
Uncaught Error: Module name <name> has not been loaded yet for context: _
```

Why does the first `require()` call just returns the module (no need to do it in a callback fashion), but the second `require()` call only works with a callback?

Comment: Unsure what the docs page is failing to explain? It's pretty thorough.

Comment: @SimonSmith The docs doesn't explain why do I need to use require() with a callback within the scope of my function. From outside I can just var dep = require('dep')

Comment: @jviotti I know this is a late reply, but as @Simon Smith pointed out in his answer, the reason it doesn't work is because it isn't simply executed like normal code.  Requirejs actually parse your function for calls to `require` so it can build a dependency tree.  In order to do that, it needs to know up front all the dependencies of a given module.  It can't do that dynamically because it needs to know every dependency before it actually fetches anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow up my comments here.

You can't use `require` without passing an array as a first argument anywhere **except** in a define callback that has `require` passed to it. And even that has limitations.

Trying to do this anywhere else will throw an error:

```
require('jquery', function() {});
```

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs

The only time you can do it is here:

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
});
```

This is just a nicer way of writing:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

});
```

The first version is known as a sugar syntax - http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar

> The AMD loader will parse out the require('') calls by using
>   Function.prototype.toString(), then internally convert the above
>   define call

I've basically just repeated what is explained on the RequireJS docs, but hopefully that makes it a little clearer.

I also covered this topic in a different context here - [How to achieve lazy loading with RequireJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911044/how-to-achieve-lazy-loading-with-requirejs/10914329#10914329)

Comment: Yeah I know that. I think my question was not well written, sorry. Tried my best to fix it now. Please take a look