# Node.js require path stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, require

I am testing some nodejs code, and this is how my directory looks like:

```
-> source  //NODE PATH=./source ...
-> plugs
   -myPlug.js
   -test.js
```

In `test.js` I try to require `myPlug.js` like this:

```
function(){
     var myRequiredPlug = require('./myPlug.js') //this works
}
```

Since the `NODE PATH` is `source`, I have also tried:

```
function(){
     var myRequiredPlug = require('./../plugs/myPlug') //also works
}
```

But I will have to require a different plug every time for my app, so I would very much like to create the path this way:

```
 function(nameOfPlug){  // nameOfPlug := myPlug
     var myPath = './../plugs/' + nameOfPlug;
     console.log(myPath === './../plugs/myPlug') // true, so same string
     var myRequiredPlug = require(myPath);  
}
```

When I try it his way, I get the error: `Error: Cannot find module './../plugs/myPlug'`

I have already tried `path.normalize`, and even to join the paths with `path.join`, but get the same results. Any ideas?

### Update: Answer

This answer can be solved using *RequireJS*, [Dynamic require in RequireJS, getting "Module name has not been loaded yet for context" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c)

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(myPath === './../plugs/nameOfPlug')` (with quotes around the string)?

Comment: jfriend00, yes, I meat it with `'...'`, thanks. And nameOfPlugs is just the name of the argument. When testing I pass myPlug as nameOfPlugs.

Comment: Try require('../plugs/myPlug') instead of require('./../plugs/myPlug')

Comment: @victork, it does not work, as I already said in the question. (`'../plugs/myPlug'` is the return value of `path.normalize('./../plugs/myPlug')`)

Answer (score 2):

I use compound lines, but not completely.

Wrong:

```
const path = './some/path.file';
const data = require(`${path}`);
```

Right:

```
const path = 'file';
const data = require(`./some/${path}.file`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function(nameOfPlug){  // nameOfPlug := myPlug
     var myPath = './../plugs/' + nameOfPlug;
     console.log(myPath === './../plugs/myPlug') // true, so same string
     var myRequiredPlug = require('' + myPath);  
}
```