# Karma/Jasmine tests fail with error: 'Uncaught Error: Module name "simple_test.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])'

Tags: requirejs, reactjs, jasmine, require, karma-jasmine

I am using Karma and Jasmine to run tests on my project built with React. When I try to run my Karma tests I get this error in the console:

```
Running "karma:test" (karma) task
WARN `start` method is deprecated since 0.13. It will be removed in 0.14. Please use 
  server = new Server(config, [done])
  server.start()
instead.
07 09 2015 14:46:56.552:WARN [plugin]: Error during loading "karma-opera-launcher" plugin:
  ENOENT, no such file or directory './config/prefs.ini'
Hash: 8344a6c0a9b3c44a5636
Version: webpack 1.12.1
Time: 6ms
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
07 09 2015 14:46:56.685:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
07 09 2015 14:46:56.689:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
07 09 2015 14:46:56.700:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
07 09 2015 14:46:56.713:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
07 09 2015 14:46:57.063:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket X4i_xm1JTKdTSJO2AAAA with id 74978391
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Module name "simple_test.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at /home/michael/repository/short-stories/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140


07 09 2015 14:46:58.890:INFO [Chromium 44.0.2403 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket K4FoGDjsszglqxvVAAAB with id 26278080
Chromium 44.0.2403 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Module name "simple_test.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at /home/michael/repository/short-stories/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:140


07 09 2015 14:47:02.441:INFO [Firefox 40.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket EJQMu5bHS1DnJLRXAAAC with id 52731426
Firefox 40.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Module name "simple_test.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at /home/michael/repository/short-stories/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:165


Warning: Task "karma:test" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I have tried the recommendations at http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded, but it didn't change the error. I also tried making my require statements into one big callback hell, but it didn't fix the issue. I'm sure the problem is that it's trying to run the tests before loading the modules, but if I can't make it wait by using callbacks, I'm not sure how to deal with the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

I'll paste my karma.conf.js, story_test.js, and test_entry.js files below. Let me know if there is more info that will help. You can view the full project on [my GitHub Repo](https://github.com/mrbgit/short-stories/tree/fix-it).

Here's my karam.conf.js:

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Jul 02 2015 15:56:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '/',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    __dirname + '/node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js',
    __dirname + '/node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
    __dirname + '/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js',
    __dirname + '/test/karma_tests/*entry.js'
    ],

    //plugins to start browsers
    plugins : [
    'karma-junit-reporter',
    'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
    'karma-chrome-launcher',
    'karma-firefox-launcher',
    'karma-opera-launcher',
    'karma-ie-launcher',
    'karma-jasmine',
    'karma-chai',
    'karma-webpack',
    'karma-requirejs',
    'karma-script-launcher'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'test/karma_tests/*test.js': ['webpack'],
        // 'test/**/*_test.js': ['webpack']
    },

    webpack: {
            // karma watches the test entry points
            // (you don't need to specify the entry option)
            // webpack watches dependencies

            // webpack configuration
        module: {
          loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader:'jsx-loader'
          }]
        }
        },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Set timeout to 100 seconds
    // browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000
  });
};
```

Here's my story_test.js:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react/addons');
var Story = require('../../app/js/components/story.jsx');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var testUtilsAdditions = require('react-testutils-additions');

  describe('Story component', function () {
    var component;

    beforeEach(function () {
      var element = React.createElement(Story);
      element.props.data = {
        storyTitle: 'front end test title',
        author : 'front end author',
        storyText : 'front end story text'
      };
      component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(element);
      });

    it('should display a story', function () {
      expect(component.props.data).toBeDefined();
      expect(component.props.data.storyTitle).toBeDefined();
      expect(component.props.data.storyTitle).toBe('front end test title');
      expect(component.props.data.author).toBe('front end author');
      expect(component.props.data.storyText).toBe('front end story text');
    });

  });
```

And finally here's the test_entry.js:

```js
'use strict';

require('./simple_test.js');
require('./story_test.js');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic require in RequireJS, getting "Module name has not been loaded yet for context" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from the http://requirejs.org project and I think is trying to get you to change from using synchronous CommonJS require calls such as;

```
require('./simple_test.js');
require('./story_test.js');
```

to asynchronous AMD calls such as;

```
require(['./simple_test.js', './story_test.js'], function() {
    // simple_test and story_test are now loaded
});
```

It's not clear to me from what you've posted which modules are requirejs/AMD and which aren't, it looks like you may possibly have a confusing mixture of the two? Sorry I can't help much more than this.