# JavaScript fails to require a file from a concat string

Tags: javascript, react-native, requirejs

I write a function which will load a file using `require()`:

```
function loadFromName(name) {
  const filename = `./${name}.initialState`;
  return require(filename).default;
}
```

When I call this method, it will fail to find the file:

```
loadFromName('tab')

> Requiring unknown module "./tab.initialState". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".
```

I tried two kinds of inline `require()`. One is success; one is failed.

```
let initialState;
const name = 'tab';
initialState = require('./tab.initialState');   // success
const filename = './' + 'tab' + '.initialState';
initialState = require(filename);               // failed
```

Why and how to fix it?

**NOTE: I use this in React-Native development**

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c

Comment: Could you write an example of `function loadFromName()`, and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Are you using require from node or requirejs, I was trying some code out and I can't replicate the issue you are having. What does your ./tab.initialState look like is it set up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic require is not supported on react native. There are lot of similar questions on stack overflow [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)