# Require.js - "Module name... has not been loaded yet for context:"

Tags: javascript, requirejs

So I'm ***very*** new to require.js and I'm confused as fug. Can someone tell me why I'm getting the message "Module name "kahoot.js" has not been loaded yet for context" when I require it at the top of the script?

```
    <script>
        require(['config'],function() {
            require(['script']);
            var Kahoot = require("kahoot.js");
            var client = new Kahoot;
            console.log("Joining kahoot...");
            client.join(gamePin,"kahoot.js");
            client.on("joined", () => {
                console.log("I joined the Kahoot!");
            });
            client.on("quizStart", quiz => {
                console.log("The quiz has started! The quiz's name is:", quiz.name);
            });
            client.on("questionStart", question => {
                console.log("A new question has started, answering the first answer.");
                question.answer(0);
            });
            client.on("quizEnd", () => {
                console.log("The quiz has ended.");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c