# Error: Module name "@google-cloud/vision" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, requirejs

I am getting this error `Module name "@google-cloud/vision" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])` ,when I run my project I have included require.js in my project and also the script tag in my html file `<script data-main = "./app.js" src = "./libs/require.js"></script>` , I went through many articles on require.js but couldn't understand what is the actual use of it and how I can resolve this error .

I also went through this thread on StackOverFlow but couldn't understand
[Dynamic require in RequireJS, getting "Module name has not been loaded yet for context" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446844/dynamic-require-in-requirejs-getting-module-name-has-not-been-loaded-yet-for-c)

Here's my code

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UPLOAD IMAGE to cloud bucket
function showResults(){
const bucketName = //name-of-bucket;
 const filename = './img2.jpg';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function uploadFile() {
  // Uploads a local file to the bucket
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
    // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
    gzip: true,
    // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
    // object you are uploading to a bucket.
    metadata: {
      // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
      // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
      // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
    },
  });

  console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
}

uploadFile().catch(console.error);
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not compatible with RequireJS which uses AMD - Asynchronous Module Definition.

AMD format looks like this:

```
define(['@google-cloud/storage'], (storage) {
  // body of your module here
});
```

The question is whether `'@google-cloud/storage'` is AMD compatible.

The simplest solution here would be to use more modern tooling like webpack or just use native ES6 modules if you support Chrome browser only