# Cypress | require() function does not work when variable is passed

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Please help me why this is not working

```js
// Does not work when varialbe pass in require()
var fileName =
  '/Users/ashdiksh/Documents/Automation/CypressTest/cypress/integration/common/pageObjects/cypressDemo.js'
var fileObj = require(fileName)
cy.log(fileObj.elements.web.email)
```

```js
  // Works fine when path is hardcoded
  var fileObj = require('/Users/ashdiksh/Documents/Automation/CypressTest/cypress/integration/common/pageObjects/cypressDemo.js');
  cy.log(fileObj.elements.web.email);
```

Error received:

> Cannot find module
> '/Users/ashdiksh/Documents/Automation/CypressTest/cypress/integration/common/pageObjects/cypressDemo.js'

Comment: This has already been answered. You can look into this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448839/4571271

Comment: Nope, that answer does not work in Cypress.

Comment: @AshokDikshit I'd be interested to know why you want to dynamically import the pageObject?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to involve the webpack compilation process to get it to work, but that's a bit of a pain to do.

Try adding an `index.js` to your `/cypress/integration/common/pageObjects` folder.

**/cypress/integration/common/pageObjects/index.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  pageObject1: require('./pageObject1'),
  pageObject2: require('./pageObject2')
}
```

Then in the test

```js
const pageObjects = require('./common/pageObjects')  // load the index.js
                                                     // relative to /cypress/integration

it('uses a dynamic pageObject', () => {

  const pageObject = pageObjects['pageObject1']

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Fody, I think this is a common issue. It may be cypress-related behavior.