# angular-resource not being properly injected with AMD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, amd, angular-resource

I fail to make angular.resource.js work with angular.js. Angular is loaded but it seems angular.resource is not.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          var require = {
            shim: {
              angular: {
                exports: "angular"
              },
              "angular.resource": {
                deps: [ "angular" ]
              }
            }
          };
        </script>
        <script src="require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="TagsController">
            Example
        </div>
        <script>
            require( ["TagsInit"] );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

TagsInit.js

```
define([
    "angular",
    "angular.resource",
], function( angular ) {
    var module = angular.module( "app.customer", [] );

    module.controller( "TagsController", function( $scope, tagsService ) {
        console.log( "TagsController executed" );
    });
    module.service( "tagsService", function( $resource ) {
        console.log( "TagsService executed" );
    });

    angular.bootstrap( document.body, [ "app.customer" ] );
});
```

I suppose it is somethign related to the shim config but I fail to realize it:

```
shim: {
    angular: {
        exports: "angular"
    },
    "angular.resource": {
        deps: [ "angular" ]
    }
}
```

Using  AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.2 and angular.resource (same version).

I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- tagsService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20tagsService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you have to pass 'ngResource' as a dependency of your angular module !

> var module = angular.module( "app.customer", ['ngResource'] );

The AMD don't break the dependency system of AngularJS.

IMHO,use requirejs with AngularJS is a bad idea ... because you've few benefits to use it. Only the script order insertion, not the modularity because Angular take is own system to manage modules.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dude I figured that out 2 minutes before you posted, but I will mark yours, thanks.

Comment: By the way requireJS and angular are necessary and recommended, angular has a module system that injects instances, requireJS is used to make your code cleaner and inject references. One may not want to load all controllers, directives and services in a single file but split the loading within multiple files to leverage async loading.

Comment: You'll see it's not my first angular project. You'll see that requirejs is not a good thing with angular. It's an awesome AMD system (for Backbone is perfect) but with Angular you'll got problems with Karma , ngDocs, protractor. But it's just my opinion :)

Comment: But the thing is if you have a huge app you will not be able to efficiently lazy load you script files and you will end up downloading all your app in a single page for the first access. I don't see today how using requireJS is scalable. I'd rather start the infrastructure in a scalable way than having to potentialy rewrite my whole application in the future.

Comment: I understand your problem bur requirejs is not lazy load by default you have to use plugin or make custom code :) : http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/ & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911044/how-to-achieve-lazy-loading-with-requirejs

Comment: I use angular JS in specific pages loaded by the server (not ngRouting). For example, I don't want to load angular JS in the index page, that's unnecessary overhead if you get what I mean. Also I don't want to add lots of scripts in the `head` of each page, I prefer loading through javascript to ensure proper dependency order.

Comment: I see yopu're more on a integrated SPA than an full SPA architecture ! I understand it it's like an hybrid system :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add `ngResource` module as a dependency for your `app.customer` module in the `requires` argument: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

```
var module = angular.module( "app.customer", ["ngResource"] );
```